# C++ architecture to represent flexible powerplant hierachy

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template-meta-programming

I m not an experienced programmer so please bear with me. As a consequence I will need to be specific on my problem which is about building an architecture to represent a power plant hierarchy:

Indeed, I m trying to construct a flexible architecture to represent contracts and pricing/analysis for multiple type of power plants. I am reading the alexandrescu book about generic design patterns and policy classes as it seems to me a good way to handle the need for flexibility and extensibility for what I want to do. Let s detail a bit :

Power plant can have different type of combustible to run (be of different types) : coal or gas or fuel. Among each of those combustible, you can choose among different sub-type of combustible (ones of different quality or Financial index). Among those sub-types, contract formula describing the delivery can be again of different types (times series averaged with FX within or via a division,etc...) Furthermore, you can be in europe and be subject to emissions reduction schemes and have to provide co2 crédits (enters in the formula of your margin), or not which depend on regulatory issues. As well, you can choose to value this power plant using different methodology etc... etc...

Thus my point is you can represent an asset in very different way which will depend on regulation, choices you make, the type of contracts you agree with another counterparty, the valuation you want to proceed and CLEARLY, you don't want to write 100 times the same code with just a little bit of change. As I said in the beginning, I am trying to find the best programming techniques to handle my program the best way. But as I said, I m new in building software achitecture. It appears to me that Policy classes would be great to handle such an architecture as they can express the kind of choices we have to make.

However, putting it in practice makes me headache. I thought of a generic object factory where Powerplant* is my abstract type where functions like  void price() or riskanalysis() would be pure virtual. Then I would need to make a hierachy based on this and derive elements

Comment: whole text wasn t published :

Comment: @user2415586 Is there a question here? And what's happened to your apostrophe (') key? Is it missing on your keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really get what do you want, but I think you should learn programming before you want to do anything related to programming.

Learning is hard and takes a lot of time but it's worth. Also, more useful than asking and getting the answer without explaination. ;)

Comment: there was an issue while I tried to publish my question. Text was printed partially. will try to put the rest